# Find in “xxx” folder today files that containing “yyy” string inside and copy those files to “zzz” folder using batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-server, findstr

I'm trying to do these:

- Search "YYY" string inside 0-day files in "XXX" folder
- Copy those files to "ZZZ" existing folder
- Rename only those files at the destination folder to "Currency_%date%_#xy.bak"

I guess it can be done with `forfiles` and `findstr` commands or through `for /f loop`.

I tried to start from:

```
 For /F "Tokens=* Delims=" %%I In ('forfiles /M *.bak /S /D 1') Do (Findstr /m "yyy" %%I)
```

Answer (score 1):

`forfiles /D 1` would get files created tomorrow or later.

Use `/D 0` (which is "today or later")

Also by default, `forfiles` give you only the filenames without the path, so `findstr` can't find them, if they are in subdirectories. To correct this behaviour, use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('FORFILES /s /M *.bak /C "cmd /c echo @path"') do ( findstr /m "yyy" %%i && copy "%%i" "zzz\" )
```

see `forfiles /?` for more infos.

Comment: Hey. This script is not working properly. btw- i know /d 0 i for today or later. i need to get the list of files to copy to another folder by searching a string in those new files. thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "not properly"? And which script?

Comment: my script is not working properly. i cant get it to work as it should.

Comment: @dej: see, if my edit helps. If not, please try to explain your problem better.

Comment: please don't ask "chameleon" questions. If you have another issue, please ask a new question.